# How to write queryXml to search out "88X211.doc" using keyword "211"?

Tags: search, web-services, query

I try to use following codes, but it does not work.
Results is

```
Status=ERROR_NO_RESULTS_FOUND
Total count =null.
```

If I use **"88x211"**, I can get the right result.
How to write queryXml to search out **"88X211.doc"** using keyword "**211**"?

```
String query_select_xml="<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'><Query>"+"<Range><Count>50</Count></Range>"+"<Context>"+
            "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>"+
            "SELECT filename,Title, Path, Description, Write, Rank, Size,author,hitHighlightedSummary,hitHighlightedProperties,contentclass FROM Scope()";
    query_select_xml+=" WHERE \"Scope\" = '"+Scope.toString();
    //query_select_xml+="' AND FREETEXT(contents,'"+Keyword.toString()+"')";
    query_select_xml+="' And (\"Filename\" like '211%') ";
    //query_select_xml+="' AND FreeText(filename,'211*')";
    query_select_xml+="ORDER BY \"Rank\" Desc "+"</QueryText>"+"</Context>" +
            "<ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior>"+
            "<IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults>"+
            "<IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults>"+
            "<IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults>" +
            "</Query></QueryPacket>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. Setting the `"Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison"` option in the settings of the managed property makes the LIKE predicate work.